# installing Python pip on windows SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install pip on my Windows 7 desktop but I'm facing this SyntaxError.

I've downloaded `Python 2.7.3`, changed the `PATH` directory, installed `easy_install.py` with no problems. However, with the straightforward instructions I'm still facing a problem with `get_pip.py`.

I downloaded `get_pip.py` and tried to run `python get_pip.py` on the command line which returns this error.

```
C:\Python27>python get_pip.py
  File "get_pip.py", line 1720
    IiDp@!k3PYyQ|v
                 ^

SyntaxError: EOF while scanning triple-quoted string literal
```

I've tried re-downloading the file, etc but this is the error I continue to receive.

Answer (score 5):

Did you just copy-paste the contents of `get-pip.py` into a blank file? If so, perhaps you accidentally copied only part of the script. If you're using Google Chrome to view it, which only takes you to a raw-text representation of `get-pip.py`, try to right-click and Save As instead, then execute the file via console.

(If you're using Firefox, clicking on `get-pip.py` from https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html will automatically download the file for you, in which case running `python get-pip.py` should cause no errors).

Answer (score 0):

Try running it directly instead of using the shell using IDLE. Works for me this way only.